# Data structure for names and pseudo-IDs: use a hash table or a BST?

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm tasked with building a data structure that stores a mapping from integer "pseudo-IDs" to names. I can insert new names into the table, where each name is associated with a number of pseudo-IDs, provided that none of the pseudo-IDs is already taken. I need to support lookups by ID and deletion by ID, where if I delete any pseudo-ID for a person, it removes all the pseudo-IDs for that person.

This program runs on a script that looks something like this:

```
I JackSmart 3 9 1009 1000009
L 1000009
I TedPumpkinhead 1 19
I PeterMeter 1 9
L 19
D 19
L 19
I JohnCritic 2 1 19
L 19
L 1
L 9
```

Here, the first character of each line determines how to interpret it.

- A line starting with I is an **insertion**. The rest of the line will consist of a name, followed by a number of pseudo-IDs for that name, then each of the pseudo-IDs. The name should be inserted unless any of the pseudo-IDs is already in use.
- A line starting with an L is a **lookup**. The line contains a pseudo-ID to look up. I need to print the name associated with it, or report that no such name exists.
- A line starting with a D is a **deletion**. The line contains the pseudo-ID to be deleted. I need to then remove the person associated with that pseudo-ID from the table, such that looking them up by *any* of their pseudo-IDs now fails.

The output of this task (according to the sample file at top) would be:

```
ok
JackSmart
ok
no
TedPumpkinhead
ok
no
ok
JohnCritic
JohnCritic
JackSmart
```

Which is the best approach here? Which data-structure should I use for this task? As there's insertion and deletion, I think it's BST. Any ideas?

Additionally, this needs to run efficiently. Each task should run in worst-case time O(log n).

Comment: How big is the data set?  vector out performs most containers for smaller data sets.

Comment: @NathanOliver     
Names can be up to 10000.

Comment: Well I would use a `std::vector` but it looks like you can't since you say it must be a O(logN) operation.

Comment: @NathanOliver So BST would be best choice?

Comment: Not sure.  The reverse lookup part is going to be a real pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through a progression of different approaches for trying to solve this problem.

One option for solving this problem would be to store some kind of associative array, where each key is a pseudo-ID and each value is a name. To do an insertion, you check whether each pseudo-ID is free. If so, you insert a key/value pair into each slot. To do a lookup, you just do a lookup by ID and return what you find. To do a deletion, you look up the key associated with the key/value pair, then iterate over the table and delete each key/value pair that has that value.

This approach is pretty fast for insertions and lookups, but it's really slow for deletions. Specifically, inserting a name with k pseudo-IDs requires O(k) associative array operations (the runtime of each depends on how we implement the associative array), looking up a name requires O(1) associative array operations, but deletion requires O(n) associative array operations.

To speed things up, one trick we can use would be to have each value store, in addition to the actual name, a list of all the pseudo-IDs associated with that name. That way, when we perform a deletion, we can look up which pseudo-IDs need to be deleted without having to literally look through every entry in the associatve array. This is a lot faster - it drops the cost of a deletion to O(k) associative array operations, where k is the number of elements deleted.

To make things *even faster*, one clever idea would be to have each value in the associative array be a pointer to a structure that stores two pieces of information: the actual name associated with the entry, plus a flag indicating whether the element has been deleted. Each pseudo-ID key then stores a pointer to this shared structure. Whenever you do a deletion, you can delete all copies of the key/value pair by just setting the "deleted" flag on the structure to true. The key/value mappings will still exist in the table, though, so whenever you do a lookup or insertion and find a key/value pair stored somewhere, before concluding that the pseudo-ID for the key is already in use, you'd check the flag. If it's marked as deleted, then you can just pretend that the ID isn't in use any more. If it's not marked as deleted, you know the entry is live and should skip it.

Here's some pseudocode for this:

```
Maintain an associative array "table."

To do a lookup(pseudoID):
   if table[pseudoID] doesn't exist, return null
   if table[pseudoID] exists, but table[pseudoID].deleted is true, return null
   return table[pseudoID].value

To do insertion(name, id1, id2, ..., idk):
   for (each id):
      if (lookup(id) != null) return false

   create a new structure:
      entry.value   = name
      entry.deleted = false 

   for (each id):
      table[id] = entry

To do delete(id):
   lookup(id) == null: return false;
   table[id].deleted = true
```

Overall, this new approach requires O(k) associative array operations for an insertion of a name with k pseudo-IDs, O(1) associative array operations for a lookup, and O(1) associative array operations for a deletion.

The question now is what the best structure would be for representing the associative array. Notice that we never need to worry about accessing anything in sorted order, so while we could use a BST, it might be better to use a hash table to accomplish this because it's (on expectation) a lot faster. So given a choice between a BST and a hash table, I'd use the hash table since it's likely going to be a lot faster. If you need to guarantee worst-case efficiency, you could use the BST, though.

With a BST, insertion runs in time O(k log n) for k IDs and both lookups and deletions will run in worst-case time O(log n). For a hash table, insertion runs in expected time O(k) for k IDs and both lookups and deletions will run in expected O(1) time.

Another option, depending on the types of numbers that you can use for pseudo-IDs, might be to use a binary trie. That would depend on how many bits can be in the keys and how dense you expect everything to be.